# Vertically align text across divs

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty sure this is a silly question but I can't figure it out. I have two side-by-side divs, with different-size headers, and I want the top header in each div to be baseline aligned. However `vertical-align: baseline` doesn't seem to work across divs. This is my code (the css is sass):

```css
.about-page-column {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 49%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;

  h3,h4 {
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: baseline; // this line obviously isn't doing anything
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: $page-title-color;
  }

  h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  h4 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="about-page-column">
    <h3>Experience</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="about-page-column">
    <h4>Links</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the result. The headers are aligned by their tops because they float to the top of the `vertical-align: top` divs.

[image: headers]

How can I align the headers within their respective divs so that they are vertically aligned by their baselines? If this is impossible, what's a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a flex-container. In this case your first  div

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="about-page-column">
    <h3>Experience</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="about-page-column">
    <h4>Links</h4>
  </div>
</div>


.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /*this is the default behavior of flex, you don't need to write it */
    justify-content: center;  /*This align the items horizontally*/
    align-items: center; /*This align the items vertically or you can use baseline*/
}
```

justify-content and align-items swap their function if flex-direction is set to column.

You can learn more about this here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. This code will make the bottom of each heading be aligned, however the underline is based off the font size so you cant really take that into account.

```
<div class="headers">
    <div class="about-page-column">
        <h3>Experience</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="about-page-column">
        <h4>Links</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.headers {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;

    .about-page-column {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 49%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;

    h3,h4 {
       padding: 5px;
       font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
       text-decoration: underline;
       color: $page-title-color;
    }

    h3 {
       font-size: 2em;
    }

    h4 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}
```